# GeoServer j_spring_security_check on Login

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have a GeoServer container that I am trying to push up to the AWS Cloud Environment.  Things work as usual (default settings ) for my 19.2.2 version of GeoServer on my localhost.

When I push the container up to the cloud, I am able to start it OK, but when I try and Login, I keep getting this "j_spring_security_check" as well as a warning about an unsecure form.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can configure things to have this j_spring_security_check go away?

https://xxxxxxx/geoserver is the AWS landing page.  It is using port 80 and port 8080 internally.  I fill out the credentials and hit login and it goes to a warning page that the form is insecure.  I continue and the login fails.  I don't have any control over the AWS configuration.  I attempted to use the Proxy Url and GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLED=true.

Comment: this might be a CSRF issue - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html

Comment: Yes, I had set those values and used the global proxy.  Everything is fine on my localhost.  On the cloud https:\\xxxx\geoserver => http:\\xxxx\ insecure form when the Login button is pressed.  I continue anyway, but does not login.  So it is setup with ports 80, 8080 with https, but the subsequent clicks seem to be http unsecure.  I don't have access to the AWS configuration, but figure something else in addition to the proxy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i solved it by enabling this part in web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
  <param-value>http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Ivica,  Thanks for the suggestion.  I will try this and let you know.  Thanks!